# Can't find Maven surefire security settings property

Tags: maven, quarkus, maven-surefire-plugin

When configuring the Surefire Maven plugin for Quarkus, I have come accross the following in the doc

```
<maven.settings>${session.request.userSettingsFile.path}</maven.settings>
```

For my project I would also need to do the same thing for the settings-security.xml file because we use password encryption.
In Quarkus this can be done using

```
<settings.security>
```

I can define this with a project property in the pom.xml with the hard-coded path of the settings-security.xml file in my CI/CD environment (it is not the default one). But ideally I would like to extract it from the Maven execution environment using something similar to ${session.request.userSettingsFile.path}

I have 2 questions (I still have a very limited experience of Maven for the moment, so please bear with me)

- I have found plenty of examples with the ${session.request.userSettingsFile.path} property, but no documentation. Anyone know where these properties are documented? It is not at all clear to me where they come from.
- Is there an equivalent to ${session.request.userSettingsFile.path} for the settings-security.xml file, or do I have to define the path in the project properties?

Thanks

Comment: Can you give a reference about the docs related to settings part of quarkus?

Comment: hi, for the surefire config I looked here
https://quarkus.io/guides/maven-tooling under Bootstrap Maven properties

Answer (score 0):

I suspect ${session} is a [MavenSession](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.8.1/maven-core/apidocs/org/apache/maven/execution/MavenSession.html) and all its getters are accessible.
Then ${session.request} is a [MavenExecutionRequest](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.8.1/maven-core/apidocs/org/apache/maven/execution/MavenExecutionRequest.html) .

Here is a [home generated dump](https://gist.github.com/cedric780/e99af41d5db7367a4405c089b39f0176) of properties accessible from [MavenSession](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.8.1/maven-core/apidocs/org/apache/maven/execution/MavenSession.html) on maven 3.8.1 , limited to 3 levels deep:

- **session.request** : [org.apache.maven.execution.MavenExecutionRequest](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.8.1/maven-core/apidocs/org/apache/maven/execution/MavenExecutionRequest)
- **session.request.toolchains** : [java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.util.List<org.apache.maven.toolchain.model.ToolchainModel>>](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.8.1/maven-core/apidocs/org/apache/maven/toolchain/model/ToolchainModel)
- **session.request.toolchains.type** : String
- **session.request.toolchains.configuration** : Object
- **session.request.toolchains.provides** : Properties
- **session.request.toolchains.sourceLevel** : String
- **session.request.mirrors** : [java.util.List<org.apache.maven.settings.Mirror>](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.8.1/maven-core/apidocs/org/apache/maven/settings/Mirror)
- **session.request.mirrors.name** : String
- **session.request.mirrors.mirrorOf** : String
- **session.request.mirrors.layout** : String
- **session.request.mirrors.url** : String
- **session.request.mirrors.mirrorOfLayouts** : String
- **session.request.mirrors.id** : String
- **session.request.mirrors.sourceLevel** : String
- **session.request.workspaceReader** : org.eclipse.aether.repository.WorkspaceReader
- **session.request.workspaceReader.repository** : org.eclipse.aether.repository.WorkspaceRepository
- **session.request.builderId** : String
- **session.request.data** : java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>
- **session.request.startTime** : Date
- **session.request.localRepository** : [org.apache.maven.artifact.repository.ArtifactRepository](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.8.1/maven-core/apidocs/org/apache/maven/artifact/repository/ArtifactRepository)
- **session.request.localRepository.key** : String
- **session.request.localRepository.id** : String
- **session.request.localRepository.protocol** : String
- **session.request.localRepository.mirroredRepositories** : [java.util.List<org.apache.maven.artifact.repository.ArtifactRepository>](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.8.1/maven-core/apidocs/org/apache/maven/artifact/repository/ArtifactRepository)
- **session.request.localRepository.proxy** : [org.apache.maven.repository.Proxy](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.8.1/maven-core/apidocs/org/apache/maven/repository/Proxy)
- **session.request.localRepository.layout** : [org.apache.maven.artifact.repository.layout.ArtifactRepositoryLayout](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.8.1/maven-core/apidocs/org/apache/maven/artifact/repository/layout/ArtifactRepositoryLayout)
- **session.request.localRepository.snapshots** : [org.apache.maven.artifact.repository.ArtifactRepositoryPolicy](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.8.1/maven-core/apidocs/org/apache/maven/artifact/repository/ArtifactRepositoryPolicy)
- **session.request.localRepository.url** : String
- **session.request.localRepository.authentication** : [org.apache.maven.artifact.repository.Authentication](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.8.1/maven-core/apidocs/org/apache/maven/artifact/repository/Authentication)
- **session.request.localRepository.basedir** : String
- **session.request.localRepository.releases** : [org.apache.maven.artifact.repository.ArtifactRepositoryPolicy](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.8.1/maven-core/apidocs/org/apache/maven/artifact/repository/ArtifactRepositoryPolicy)
- **session.request.userProperties** : Properties
- **session.request.goals** : java.util.List<java.lang.String>
- **session.request.pluginGroups** : java.util.List<java.lang.String>
- **session.request.loggingLevel** : int
- **session.request.repositoryCache** : org.eclipse.aether.RepositoryCache
- **session.request.pom** : java.io.File
- **session.request.resumeFrom** : String
- **session.request.activeProfiles** : java.util.List<java.lang.String>
- **session.request.baseDirectory** : String
- **session.request.makeBehavior** : String
- **session.request.profiles** : [java.util.List<org.apache.maven.model.Profile>](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.8.1/maven-core/apidocs/org/apache/maven/model/Profile)
- **session.request.profiles.id** : String
- **session.request.profiles.build** : [org.apache.maven.model.BuildBase](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.8.1/maven-core/apidocs/org/apache/maven/model/BuildBase)
- **session.request.profiles.source** : String
- **session.request.profiles.activation** : [org.apache.maven.model.Activation](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.8.1/maven-core/apidocs/org/apache/maven/model/Activation)
- **session.request.profiles.location** : [org.apache.maven.model.InputLocation](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.8.1/maven-core/apidocs/org/apache/maven/model/InputLocation)
- **session.request.profiles.properties** : Properties
- **session.request.profiles.distributionManagement** : [org.apache.maven.model.DistributionManagement](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.8.1/maven-core/apidocs/org/apache/maven/model/DistributionManagement)
- **session.request.profiles.dependencyManagement** : [org.apache.maven.model.DependencyManagement](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.8.1/maven-core/apidocs/org/apache/maven/model/DependencyManagement)
- **session.request.profiles.pluginRepositories** : [java.util.List<org.apache.maven.model.Repository>](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.8.1/maven-core/apidocs/org/apache/maven/model/Repository)
- **session.request.profiles.dependencies** : [java.util.List<org.apache.maven.model.Dependency>](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.8.1/maven-core/apidocs/org/apache/maven/model/Dependency)
- **session.request.profiles.repositories** : [java.util.List<org.apache.maven.model.Repository>](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.8.1/maven-core/apidocs/org/apache/maven/model/Repository)
- **session.request.profiles.modules** : java.util.List<java.lang.String>
- **session.request.profiles.reporting** : [org.apache.maven.model.Reporting](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.8.1/maven-core/apidocs/org/apache/maven/model/Reporting)
- **session.request.profiles.reports** : Object
- **session.request.proxies** : [java.util.List<org.apache.maven.settings.Proxy>](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.8.1/maven-core/apidocs/org/apache/maven/settings/Proxy)
- **session.request.proxies.port** : int
- **session.request.proxies.protocol** : String
- **session.request.proxies.host** : String
- **session.request.proxies.password** : String
- **session.request.proxies.username** : String
- **session.request.proxies.nonProxyHosts** : String
- **session.request.proxies.id** : String
- **session.request.proxies.sourceLevel** : String
- **session.request.servers** : [java.util.List<org.apache.maven.settings.Server>](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.8.1/maven-core/apidocs/org/apache/maven/settings/Server)
- **session.request.servers.configuration** : Object
- **session.request.servers.directoryPermissions** : String
- **session.request.servers.password** : String
- **session.request.servers.privateKey** : String
- **session.request.servers.username** : String
- **session.request.servers.passphrase** : String
- **session.request.servers.filePermissions** : String
- **session.request.servers.id** : String
- **session.request.servers.sourceLevel** : String
- **session.request.globalSettingsFile** : java.io.File
- **session.request.projectBuildingRequest** : [org.apache.maven.project.ProjectBuildingRequest](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.8.1/maven-core/apidocs/org/apache/maven/project/ProjectBuildingRequest)
- **session.request.projectBuildingRequest.localRepository** : [org.apache.maven.artifact.repository.ArtifactRepository](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.8.1/maven-core/apidocs/org/apache/maven/artifact/repository/ArtifactRepository)
- **session.request.projectBuildingRequest.userProperties** : Properties
- **session.request.projectBuildingRequest.profiles** : [java.util.List<org.apache.maven.model.Profile>](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.8.1/maven-core/apidocs/org/apache/maven/model/Profile)
- **session.request.projectBuildingRequest.activeProfileIds** : java.util.List<java.lang.String>
- **session.request.projectBuildingRequest.repositoryMerging** : [org.apache.maven.project.ProjectBuildingRequest$RepositoryMerging](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.8.1/maven-core/apidocs/org/apache/maven/project/ProjectBuildingRequest$RepositoryMerging)
- **session.request.projectBuildingRequest.inactiveProfileIds** : java.util.List<java.lang.String>
- **session.request.projectBuildingRequest.systemProperties** : Properties
- **session.request.projectBuildingRequest.repositorySession** : org.eclipse.aether.RepositorySystemSession
- **session.request.projectBuildingRequest.remoteRepositories** : [java.util.List<org.apache.maven.artifact.repository.ArtifactRepository>](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.8.1/maven-core/apidocs/org/apache/maven/artifact/repository/ArtifactRepository)
- **session.request.projectBuildingRequest.pluginArtifactRepositories** : [java.util.List<org.apache.maven.artifact.repository.ArtifactRepository>](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.8.1/maven-core/apidocs/org/apache/maven/artifact/repository/ArtifactRepository)
- **session.request.projectBuildingRequest.project** : [org.apache.maven.project.MavenProject](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.8.1/maven-core/apidocs/org/apache/maven/project/MavenProject)
- **session.request.projectBuildingRequest.buildStartTime** : Date
- **session.request.projectBuildingRequest.validationLevel** : int
- **session.request.selectedProjects** : java.util.List<java.lang.String>
- **session.request.degreeOfConcurrency** : int
- **session.request.systemProperties** : Properties
- **session.request.globalChecksumPolicy** : String
- **session.request.reactorFailureBehavior** : String
- **session.request.transferListener** : org.eclipse.aether.transfer.TransferListener
- **session.request.localRepositoryPath** : java.io.File
- **session.request.inactiveProfiles** : java.util.List<java.lang.String>
- **session.request.userSettingsFile** : java.io.File
- **session.request.excludedProjects** : java.util.List<java.lang.String>
- **session.request.globalToolchainsFile** : java.io.File
- **session.request.remoteRepositories** : [java.util.List<org.apache.maven.artifact.repository.ArtifactRepository>](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.8.1/maven-core/apidocs/org/apache/maven/artifact/repository/ArtifactRepository)
- **session.request.multiModuleProjectDirectory** : java.io.File
- **session.request.pluginArtifactRepositories** : [java.util.List<org.apache.maven.artifact.repository.ArtifactRepository>](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.8.1/maven-core/apidocs/org/apache/maven/artifact/repository/ArtifactRepository)
- **session.request.executionListener** : [org.apache.maven.execution.ExecutionListener](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.8.1/maven-core/apidocs/org/apache/maven/execution/ExecutionListener)
- **session.request.eventSpyDispatcher** : [org.apache.maven.eventspy.internal.EventSpyDispatcher](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.8.1/maven-core/apidocs/org/apache/maven/eventspy/internal/EventSpyDispatcher)
- **session.request.eventSpyDispatcher.eventSpies** : [java.util.List<org.apache.maven.eventspy.EventSpy>](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.8.1/maven-core/apidocs/org/apache/maven/eventspy/EventSpy)
- **session.request.userToolchainsFile** : java.io.File
- **session.projectMap** : [java.util.Map<java.lang.String, org.apache.maven.project.MavenProject>](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.8.1/maven-core/apidocs/org/apache/maven/project/MavenProject)
- **session.result** : [org.apache.maven.execution.MavenExecutionResult](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.8.1/maven-core/apidocs/org/apache/maven/execution/MavenExecutionResult)
- **session.result.topologicallySortedProjects** : [java.util.List<org.apache.maven.project.MavenProject>](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.8.1/maven-core/apidocs/org/apache/maven/project/MavenProject)
- **session.result.dependencyResolutionResult** : [org.apache.maven.project.DependencyResolutionResult](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.8.1/maven-core/apidocs/org/apache/maven/project/DependencyResolutionResult)
- **session.result.dependencyResolutionResult.dependencies** : org.eclipse.aether.graph.Dependency
- **session.result.dependencyResolutionResult.unresolvedDependencies** : org.eclipse.aether.graph.Dependency
- **session.result.dependencyResolutionResult.collectionErrors** : java.util.List<java.lang.Exception>
- **session.result.dependencyResolutionResult.resolutionErrors** : java.util.List<java.lang.Exception>
- **session.result.dependencyResolutionResult.resolvedDependencies** : org.eclipse.aether.graph.Dependency
- **session.result.dependencyResolutionResult.dependencyGraph** : org.eclipse.aether.graph.DependencyNode
- **session.result.exceptions** : java.util.List<java.lang.Throwable>
- **session.result.project** : [org.apache.maven.project.MavenProject](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.8.1/maven-core/apidocs/org/apache/maven/project/MavenProject)
- **session.result.buildSummary** : [org.apache.maven.execution.BuildSummary](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.8.1/maven-core/apidocs/org/apache/maven/execution/BuildSummary)
- **session.result.buildSummary.time** : long
- **session.result.buildSummary.project** : [org.apache.maven.project.MavenProject](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.8.1/maven-core/apidocs/org/apache/maven/project/MavenProject)
- **session.startTime** : Date
- **session.projects** : [java.util.List<org.apache.maven.project.MavenProject>](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.8.1/maven-core/apidocs/org/apache/maven/project/MavenProject)
- **session.allProjects** : [java.util.List<org.apache.maven.project.MavenProject>](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.8.1/maven-core/apidocs/org/apache/maven/project/MavenProject)
- **session.localRepository** : [org.apache.maven.artifact.repository.ArtifactRepository](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.8.1/maven-core/apidocs/org/apache/maven/artifact/repository/ArtifactRepository)
- **session.userProperties** : Properties
- **session.goals** : java.util.List<java.lang.String>
- **session.settings** : [org.apache.maven.settings.Settings](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.8.1/maven-core/apidocs/org/apache/maven/settings/Settings)
- **session.settings.modelEncoding** : String
- **session.settings.interactiveMode** : Boolean
- **session.settings.activeProxy** : [org.apache.maven.settings.Proxy](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.8.1/maven-core/apidocs/org/apache/maven/settings/Proxy)
- **session.settings.mirrors** : [java.util.List<org.apache.maven.settings.Mirror>](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.8.1/maven-core/apidocs/org/apache/maven/settings/Mirror)
- **session.settings.server** : [org.apache.maven.settings.Server](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.8.1/maven-core/apidocs/org/apache/maven/settings/Server)
- **session.settings.localRepository** : String
- **session.settings.pluginGroups** : java.util.List<java.lang.String>
- **session.settings.activeProfiles** : java.util.List<java.lang.String>
- **session.settings.profiles** : [java.util.List<org.apache.maven.settings.Profile>](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.8.1/maven-core/apidocs/org/apache/maven/settings/Profile)
- **session.settings.profiles.properties** : Properties
- **session.settings.profiles.pluginRepositories** : [java.util.List<org.apache.maven.settings.Repository>](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.8.1/maven-core/apidocs/org/apache/maven/settings/Repository)
- **session.settings.profiles.repositories** : [java.util.List<org.apache.maven.settings.Repository>](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.8.1/maven-core/apidocs/org/apache/maven/settings/Repository)
- **session.settings.profiles.activation** : [org.apache.maven.settings.Activation](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.8.1/maven-core/apidocs/org/apache/maven/settings/Activation)
- **session.settings.profiles.id** : String
- **session.settings.profiles.sourceLevel** : String
- **session.settings.proxies** : [java.util.List<org.apache.maven.settings.Proxy>](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.8.1/maven-core/apidocs/org/apache/maven/settings/Proxy)
- **session.settings.servers** : [java.util.List<org.apache.maven.settings.Server>](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.8.1/maven-core/apidocs/org/apache/maven/settings/Server)
- **session.settings.mirrorOf** : [org.apache.maven.settings.Mirror](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.8.1/maven-core/apidocs/org/apache/maven/settings/Mirror)
- **session.settings.profilesAsMap** : [java.util.Map<java.lang.String, org.apache.maven.settings.Profile>](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.8.1/maven-core/apidocs/org/apache/maven/settings/Profile)
- **session.settings.sourceLevel** : String
- **session.currentProject** : [org.apache.maven.project.MavenProject](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.8.1/maven-core/apidocs/org/apache/maven/project/MavenProject)
- **session.pluginGroups** : java.util.List<java.lang.String>
- **session.topLevelProject** : [org.apache.maven.project.MavenProject](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.8.1/maven-core/apidocs/org/apache/maven/project/MavenProject)
- **session.pluginContext** : java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>
- **session.sortedProjects** : [java.util.List<org.apache.maven.project.MavenProject>](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.8.1/maven-core/apidocs/org/apache/maven/project/MavenProject)
- **session.repositoryCache** : [org.apache.maven.artifact.repository.RepositoryCache](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.8.1/maven-core/apidocs/org/apache/maven/artifact/repository/RepositoryCache)
- **session.eventDispatcher** : [org.apache.maven.monitor.event.EventDispatcher](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.8.1/maven-core/apidocs/org/apache/maven/monitor/event/EventDispatcher)
- **session.container** : org.codehaus.plexus.PlexusContainer
- **session.container.context** : org.codehaus.plexus.context.Context
- **session.container.context.contextData** : java.util.Map<java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object>
- **session.container.componentDescriptorList** : java.util.List<org.codehaus.plexus.component.repository.ComponentDescriptor>
- **session.container.componentDescriptorList** : java.util.List<org.codehaus.plexus.component.repository.ComponentDescriptor<?>>
- **session.container.componentDescriptor** : org.codehaus.plexus.component.repository.ComponentDescriptor<?>
- **session.container.componentDescriptor** : org.codehaus.plexus.component.repository.ComponentDescriptor
- **session.container.componentDescriptorMap** : java.util.Map<java.lang.String, org.codehaus.plexus.component.repository.ComponentDescriptor<?>>
- **session.container.componentDescriptorMap** : java.util.Map<java.lang.String, org.codehaus.plexus.component.repository.ComponentDescriptor>
- **session.container.containerRealm** : org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm
- **session.container.containerRealm.resource** : java.net.URL
- **session.container.containerRealm.resources** : java.util.Enumeration<java.net.URL>
- **session.container.containerRealm.id** : String
- **session.container.containerRealm.importClassLoader** : ClassLoader
- **session.container.containerRealm.parentClassLoader** : ClassLoader
- **session.container.containerRealm.parentRealm** : org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm
- **session.container.containerRealm.importRealms** : org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm
- **session.container.containerRealm.strategy** : org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.Strategy
- **session.container.containerRealm.world** : org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.ClassWorld
- **session.container.containerRealm.resourceAsStream** : java.io.InputStream
- **session.container.containerRealm.uRLs** : [Ljava.net.URL;
- **session.container.containerRealm.platformClassLoader** : ClassLoader
- **session.container.containerRealm.systemClassLoader** : ClassLoader
- **session.container.containerRealm.name** : String
- **session.container.containerRealm.systemResourceAsStream** : java.io.InputStream
- **session.container.containerRealm.systemResource** : java.net.URL
- **session.container.containerRealm.systemResources** : java.util.Enumeration<java.net.URL>
- **session.container.containerRealm.parent** : ClassLoader
- **session.container.containerRealm.unnamedModule** : Module
- **session.container.containerRealm.definedPackage** : Package
- **session.container.containerRealm.definedPackages** : Package[]
- **session.container.lookupRealm** : org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm
- **session.executionRootDirectory** : String
- **session.projectBuildingRequest** : [org.apache.maven.project.ProjectBuildingRequest](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.8.1/maven-core/apidocs/org/apache/maven/project/ProjectBuildingRequest)
- **session.systemProperties** : Properties
- **session.repositorySession** : org.eclipse.aether.RepositorySystemSession
- **session.reactorFailureBehavior** : String
- **session.projectDependencyGraph** : [org.apache.maven.execution.ProjectDependencyGraph](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.8.1/maven-core/apidocs/org/apache/maven/execution/ProjectDependencyGraph)
- **session.projectDependencyGraph.allProjects** : [java.util.List<org.apache.maven.project.MavenProject>](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.8.1/maven-core/apidocs/org/apache/maven/project/MavenProject)
- **session.projectDependencyGraph.sortedProjects** : [java.util.List<org.apache.maven.project.MavenProject>](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.8.1/maven-core/apidocs/org/apache/maven/project/MavenProject)
- **session.projectDependencyGraph.downstreamProjects** : [java.util.List<org.apache.maven.project.MavenProject>](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.8.1/maven-core/apidocs/org/apache/maven/project/MavenProject)
- **session.projectDependencyGraph.upstreamProjects** : [java.util.List<org.apache.maven.project.MavenProject>](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.8.1/maven-core/apidocs/org/apache/maven/project/MavenProject)
- **session.executionProperties** : Properties